# want to execute disNone() function inside saveInfo() function when click on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I want to execute `disNone()` inside `saveInfo()` when the button is clicked:
Error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'disNone' of undefined

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Login extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        dispNone:"dispNone",
        message:"dispNone"
    };
    this.disNone = this.disNone.bind(this);
};

 disNone(){
    this.setState({
        dispNone: "dispNone",
        message:"dispBlock"
    });
}


 saveInfo(){
    this.disNone(); 
 }

render() {
    return (
       <div>
         // other code
          <button onClick={this.saveInfo}>Sign up</button>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'disNone' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor, besides `this.disNone = this.disNone.bind(this)`, you also need to put

```
this.saveInfo = this.saveInfo.bind(this);
```

the error is because `safeInfo` does not know what `this` means, which gives you the error that `disNone is undefined`

**EDIT:** We do this in the constructor because we only need to `bind` the function once. Alternatively you could write it in the `render` function as well, but that means everytime the `render` function executes, you rebind the the function which is kind of a waste.

A third alternative is to use the `() => this.saveInfo()` inside the render function, this does not require any kind of binding anywhere, but again, this function has to be "created" every time the `render` function runs.

Comment: works perfect, thanks
can you explain me why we use  
this.disNone = this.disNone.bind(this);
this.saveInfo = this.saveInfo.bind(this);
in constructor function?

Comment: added some more details, also here is a nice article that sums up different ways: https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/

Answer (score 0):

add

> this.saveInfo = this.saveInfo.bind(this);

in your constructor.
SaveInfo method is not having access to this.